# how to do vlookup in python for only one column from multiple excel files?

Tags: python, excel, automation

Lets say I have 5 Excel files named as A, B, C, D, X. Now I want to automate this vlookup in python. Suppose I want to have vlookup data in X file from rest 4 files. All the files have common column named as Email. Using that common column I want to fill the data in X file. How to automate this in Python ?

I'm expecting a automation in python for vlookup.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: have a vlookup for each file and an if() or choose() to pick the relevant one.